# Can someone help me to install the netflix's VMAF library in Ubuntu

Tags: ffmpeg

First of all, I have to say that I am not very experienced in ubuntu.
I would like to install this library to use with FFMPEG.

I am following these steps, but I can manage to install it well...

https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/resource/doc/VMAF_Python_library.md

Could someone tell me what are the exact steps (commands) that I have to follow.

On the other hand, someone knows if there are other metrics that can ffmpeg calculates directly (apart from PSNR or SSIM)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The link you provided is just to install the VMAF python library. To use VMAF with ffmpeg you need to install  [libvmaf](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/libvmaf/README.md) first and then compile ffmpeg with libvmaf filter enabled. However, as one user suggests, you can use already compiled ffmpeg packages https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Moving to your questions. These are the step by step I followed to install FFmpeg+VMAF over an Ubuntu 20.04:

Installing dependencies:

```
apt update -qq
apt install pkg-config -y
apt-get install --no-install-recommends\
    ninja-build \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-wheel \
    ninja-build \
    wget \
    doxygen \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    cmake \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    pkg-config \
    make \
    nasm \
    yasm -y
pip3 install --user meson
```

Installing libvmaf:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
wget https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/archive/v1.5.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf  v1.5.1.tar.gz
cd vmaf-1.5.1/libvmaf/
meson build --buildtype release
ninja -vC build
ninja -vC build test
ninja -vC build install
```

Installing ffmpeg:

```
wget https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.2.2.tar.bz2 && tar xjf ffmpeg-4.2.2.tar.bz2 
cd ffmpeg-4.2.2
./configure --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3
make
make install
```

Sometimes, depending on your OS, you also need to setup your `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Download an already compiled `ffmpeg` from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). It supports the [libvmaf filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libvmaf). For instructions on how to install it see the [FAQ](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [detailed guide on OTTVerse](https://ottverse.com/vmaf-ffmpeg-ubuntu-compilation-installation-usage-guide/) for compiling and installing FFmpeg with VMAF support on Ubuntu 18.04. It shouldn't take you more than a few minutes.

Be aware, that VMAF's `libvmaf` library will soon be dropped and replaced with a new library called `libvmaf_rc`. Hopefully, its compilation with FFmpeg will remain smooth as well.

Answer (score 0):

- `sudo apt-get install nasm doxygen ninja-build meson`
- Download VMAF source from [here](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/releases) and extract it.
- `cd` into the vmaf source code folder.
- `cd` into the `libvmaf` folder.
- `meson build --buildtype release`
- `ninja -vC build`
- `ninja -vC build install`
- Download ffmpeg source code from [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).
- Extract the source code and `cd` into the ffmpeg source code folder.
- `./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3`
- `sudo make`
- `sudo make install`
- Add the following `export` line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.
- Run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`.

[Attribution](https://github.com/yash1994/Build-FFmpeg-with-libvmaf).